# How can I access other PropertyValues at runtime with a custom PropertyValueEditor

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

I have a C# WPF application that uses a PropertyGrid and custom PropertyValueEditors...  To help simplify property entry the custom PropertyValueEditors need to be able to access other properties within the same class...  for instance (bad untested example, but should get across my need)...

```
public class AnimationFrames
{
   public List<Bitmap> Frames { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, List<int>> Animations { get; set; }
}
```

I would set a custom PropertyValueEditor on Animations - the Dialog for editing Animations would need access to the Frames property...

Any idea on how I could do this (BTW:  I'm not doing anything with graphics animations, but I thought it might be a good example).

For those of you who are interested I'm using the WpfPropertyGrid editor (with some modifications) from:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87715/Native-WPF-PropertyGrid

Comment: I still don't understand what do you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to force the getter to invoke the dialog by setting the value to null and having the getter check for null - the getter has full access to the class...